# Data tables - Loading JSON response in datatable

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, datatables

Using REST API, I am getting the JSON response from the below Ajax hit for loading datatable.

I am getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.`

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "bSort" : false,
    "bDestroy" : true,
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing" : false,
    "bFilter" : true,
    "bServerSide" : true,
    "bAutoWidth" : false,
    "sAjaxSource" : 'exampledatagrid.json?token=' + sessionId,
    "aoColumns" : [{
        "mData" : "0",
        "mData" : "1",
        "mData" : "2",
        "mData" : "3"
    }],
    "fnServerParams" : function(aoData) {
        alert(aoData);
        aoData.push({
            "name" : "colNameMode",
            "value" : "userStatusList"
        }, {
            "name" : "colName_0",
            "value" : "userIDList"
        }, {
            "name" : "colName_1",
            "value" : "userNameList"
        }, {
            "name" : "colName_2",
            "value" : "userRemarksList"
        });
    },
    "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
        alert(aData);
    },
    "fnDrawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
        if ( oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered ) {
            for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ) {
                $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr ).html( i+1 );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

JSON response is :

```
{"userRemarksList":["TECHNOLOGY","GUEST","HOUSE","SECURITY"],"userIDList":[23,45,23,54],"userNameList":["Michael","Danny","Rahil","Ramesh"],"userStatusList":[0,0,1,1]}
```

I want to know whether I have to change my JSON format or if I can retrieve from the above JSON response itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by making a change in my back-end by quering the results using hibernate "org.hibernate.query". from this i was able to obtain the list of records (one-by-one) and load it into the grid respectively.